# expand the list item based on the id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drupal

I have the following HTML content on the FAQ page.

```
<div id="block-companysubtheme-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block panel o-box">
  
   <article data-history-node-id="1576" about="/services/faq">
      <div class="node__content">
         
         <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
            <h2>General</h2>
            <ul class="list--faq">
               <li aria-controls="faq-0" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">How can I contact the company with questions about your&nbsp;services?</li>
               <li id="faq-0" style="display: none;">Please contact us through phone.</li>
               <li aria-controls="faq-1" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">How old does parts need to be for food testing?</li>
               <li id="faq-1" style="display: none;">There is no time limit for testing.</li>
               <li aria-controls="faq-2" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">What is the cost of services?</li>
               <li id="faq-2" style="display: none;">The cost of services  varies.&nbsp;See the information page specific for the details</li>
               <li aria-controls="faq-3" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">What are my payment options?</li>
               <li id="faq-3" style="display: none;">You can pay online or mail a check.</li>
              
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
   </article>
  
</div>
```

Notice that all the answer list elements have `style` set to `display:none;` as shown above. Once used clicks on the question, let's say I clicked on this question  `<li aria-controls="faq-0" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">How can I contact the company with questions about your&nbsp;services?</li>`, then the CSS of its answer changes to the following:
`<li id="faq-0" style="display: block; transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;" data-slide-toggle="true">Please contact us through phone</li>`

Overall, the above shared HTML content will look like this with the open question:

```
<div id="block-companysubtheme-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block panel o-box">
  
   <article data-history-node-id="1576" about="/services/faq">
      <div class="node__content">
         
         <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
            <h2>General</h2>
           <ul class="list--faq">
                <li aria-controls="faq-0" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">How can I contact the company with questions about your&nbsp;services?</li>
                <li id="faq-0" style="display: block; transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;" data-slide-toggle="true">Please contact us through phone</li>
                <li aria-controls="faq-1" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">How old does an animal need to be for DNA testing?</li>
                <li aria-controls="faq-1" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">How old do parts need to be for food testing?</li>
                <li id="faq-1" style="display: none;">There is no time limit for testing.</li>
                <li aria-controls="faq-2" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">What is the cost of services?</li>
                <li id="faq-2" style="display: none;">The cost of services  varies.&nbsp;See the information page specific for the details</li>
                <li aria-controls="faq-3" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">What are my payment options?</li>
                <li id="faq-3" style="display: none;">You can pay online or mail a check.</li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
   </article>
  
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

If a user is directed to this page from an external website with the URL, let's say: `http://localhost:8080/services/faq#faq-0`, then I want to expand the list for them.

The way I am attempting it like this in my javascript code (inside Drupal behavior ):

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
alert(hash);
$(hash).show();
```

But this does nothing. So do I need to specifically insert the CSS `style="display: block; transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;" data-slide-toggle="true"` for the list element with `id`  `faq-0`  using jQuery? Is that the way to proceed?

Comment: You need to call that javascript code inside the load event of javascript (or ready event in the jQuery). Also you need to call the same code on click event.

Comment: I'm calling it inside Drupal behavior so that's equivalent to calling it inside ready. There's no click event set by me and the HTML doesn't show any onclick handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I was going to just add a class that automatically added the proper styles. However, since we don't know how the FAQs are actually being shown/hidden, I went with just directly changing the CSS itself.

```js
let hash = window.location.hash;

//testing
hash = "#faq-1";

if(hash){
  $(hash).css({"display" : "block","transition":"all 300ms ease-in 0s"}).data("slide-toggle",true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-companysubtheme-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block panel o-box">
  
   <article data-history-node-id="1576" about="/services/faq">
      <div class="node__content">
         
         <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
            <h2>General</h2>
            <ul class="list--faq">
               <li aria-controls="faq-0" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">How can I contact the company with questions about your&nbsp;services?</li>
               <li id="faq-0" style="display: none;">Please contact us through phone.</li>
               <li aria-controls="faq-1" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">How old does parts need to be for food testing?</li>
               <li id="faq-1" style="display: none;">There is no time limit for testing.</li>
               <li aria-controls="faq-2" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">What is the cost of services?</li>
               <li id="faq-2" style="display: none;">The cost of services  varies.&nbsp;See the information page specific for the details</li>
               <li aria-controls="faq-3" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">What are my payment options?</li>
               <li id="faq-3" style="display: none;">You can pay online or mail a check.</li>
              
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
   </article>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine if I type `http://localhost:8080/services/faq#faq-20` on a page and takes me to that list element.  However, if I'm editing the above URL on the same tab with something different `http://localhost:8080/services/faq#faq-21` it won't do anything. Maybe it has to do with my local Drupal code where I've to flush everything before testing new functionality. When I close the browser window, flush everything from Drupal and then run `http://localhost:8080/services/faq#faq-21` on a new browser incognito window, it works fine.

Comment: Just realized that I've to refresh the page after changing the number in the end and it works fine with new ID.

Comment: With the above approach, I noticed that it shows only the answer based on the id received from the hash. I am wondering if the question can also be displayed and the answer below it.